# Drb and "is recycled object" exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drb

I'm running in a strange issue. 
My controller calls a drb object

```
@request_handler = DRbObject.new(nil, url)
availability_result = @request_handler.fetch_availability(request, @reservation_search, params[:selected_room_rates])
```

and this Drb object is making some searches.

but sometimes, in a linux environments, I get a "0xdba87b30 is recycled object" with this stacktrace

```
--- 
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:375:in `_id2ref'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:375:in `to_obj'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1402:in `to_obj'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1704:in `to_obj'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:613:in `recv_request'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:911:in `recv_request'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1530:in `init_with_client'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1542:in `setup_message'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1494:in `perform'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1589:in `main_loop'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1585:in `loop'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1585:in `main_loop'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1581:in `start'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1581:in `main_loop'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1430:in `run'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1427:in `start'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1427:in `run'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1347:in `initialize'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1627:in `new'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1627:in `start_service'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) ./core/request_handler.rb:244
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `gem_original_require'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `require'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:355:in `new_constants_in'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) core/request_handler.rb:31
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) core/request_handler.rb:29:in `each'
- (druby://10.254.143.159:9001) core/request_handler.rb:29
- app/drops/room_drop.rb:18:in `room_rates'
- lib/liquid/liquid_templates.rb:47:in `parse_template'
- lib/liquid/liquid_templates.rb:21:in `render_liquid_template_without_layout'
- app/helpers/skins_helper.rb:6:in `render_respond_by_format'
- app/helpers/skins_helper.rb:4:in `render_respond_by_format'
- app/helpers/skins_helper.rb:25:in `render_availability_action'
- app/controllers/web_reservations_controller.rb:109:in `availability_simplified'
- /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
- /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

The strange thing is that I can't reproduce the error in my (windows) development machine, but I get it only in my linux testing server (2 mongrels instead of one in my machine).

What's wrong? I think it is a garbage collector problem (object collected before reusing it), but I don't understand where I'm doing something wrong. I simply create the object in my controller and call a method on it.

Any idea?

Thanks!
Roberto

Comment: You seem to be missing the top of the stack trace where it actually shows the error, could you please include that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error means that you're trying to serve an object that's been garbage collected, which usually happens because the object went out of scope on the **server**.

Your safest bet is figuring out why the object was prematurely garbage-collected in the first place. Alternatively, you could disable the server's GC by calling `GC.disable`, which is usually a bad idea, especially if your server is long-running.

Comment: Obviously, as said, you should _not_ disable the GC but trying to do so temporarily will let you know whether or not this is your issue

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to delay garbage collection **for the object passed to the client** on the server:

```rb
  DRb.install_id_conv TimerIdConv.new 60 # one minute
```

See https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/drb/rdoc/DRb/TimerIdConv.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are calling DRb.start_service more than once in the server?